# Mongoid after save call back runs twice

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongoid4

```
class SubJob
  field :total_qty
end

class Part

  belongs_to :sub_job
  after_save :update_inventory, if: ready_for_invoice
  after_save :update_total_qty

  def update_inventory
    # creating one more part2 
    part2 = Part.create(ready_for_invoice: false)
  end

  def update_total_qty
    # updating total qty on sub job
  end
end
```

when I creating `p1 = Part.create` it creates `part2` object as well. But it updates qty twice for `part2` sub job. I have checked history trackers for `part2` object. It show two history trackers but only one `part2` object on db. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm not hundred percent on what your error/issue is, but I am hoping running through what is going on in your code will help:

I am assuming ready_for_invoice defaults to true.

Therefore what you have coded is saying:

*create a new part, set ready_for_invoice to true*

```
p1 = Part.create
```

*after saving, if ready_for_invoice = true (which it does)*

```
# run update_inventory first
```

*create a new part, set ready_for_invoice to false*

```
p2 = Part.create(ready_for_invoice: false)
```

*after saving p2*

```
# run update_total_qty (doing whatever that does)
```

*after saving p1*

```
# run update_total_qty (doing whatever that does)
```